# Unknown provider when setting up Jasmine AngularJS service test

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, jasmine

I have an angularjs service which calculates a products price based on discounts, quantity, etc.  I'm trying to write a jasmine test to call this service, passing in test data.  I get an error that the app is missing it's dependencies.  I don't want to have to load Ui router, shouldn't mocks take care of that?

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is my Jasmine SpecRunner.html.  The Web project I am testing is in a different project than my Jasmine test project.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:54411/Scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:54411/Scripts/vendor/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:54411/Scripts/app.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <script src="http://localhost:54411/Scripts/services/productPriceCalculatorSvc.js"></script>

    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="spec/ProductPriceCalculatorSpec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The spec file:

```
describe("Product Price Calculator service test", function () {
    describe("when I call product price calculator.calculateCustomerDiscPrice", function () {
        var sut;

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('quoteMasterApp');
            inject(function(productPriceCalculatorSvc) {
                sut = productPriceCalculatorSvc;
            });
        });

        it('can calculate customer discount price', function() {
            productPriceCalculatorSvc.calculateCustomerDiscPrice(null, null);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my service declaration.

```
myApp.service("productPriceCalculatorSvc", [
    function() {
        return {
            calculateCustomerDiscPrice: function(product, conversionRate) {
                // calculations occur here
                });
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the framework how to find your service.

Something like:

```
describe("ProductPriceCalculator", function () {
    var productPriceCalculatorSvc;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('productPriceCalculatorSvcFactory'); 
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        productPriceCalculatorSvc = $injector.get('productPriceCalculatorSvcFactory');
    }));

    it('can calculate customer discount price', function () {
        productPriceCalculatorSvc.calculateCustomerDiscPrice();
    });
});
```

See more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: What is the productPriceCalculatorSvcFactory you are referencing?  My app doesn't use a factory for the service.

Comment: This should be so easy.  A single service with no dependencies.  4 hours in and no progress :(  And I thought angularjs was suppose to be testable.

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: No luck, spent too much time on it so I'm forced to move on with no client side tests unfortunately :(

Comment: Dear Ryan Langton I found an example that works I have made a copy in my own JSFiddle (but it's not my code) http://jsfiddle.net/ChtiSuisse/nm6qj257/
In my case it's not complete yet (my own service returns $http so I need to mock it)
Once I have something that works I'll make a new Fiddle out of it and post the code below in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case : test a controller that calls a service.
Here is what I have in my decribe

```
describe('Controller Test', function () {  

    var scope, ctrl;  
    // load your controllers including myController
    beforeEach(module('mycontrollers'));

    // load your services (do not forget to include them in your spec runner !)
    // there should be myService defined in this module
    beforeEach(module('myservices'));

    // It seems a good practice to inject nothing in "it"
    // Everything is injected in beforeEach
    // here the controller uses theService and set some value in the scope
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, ReportProductService) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('myController', {
        $scope: scope,
        theService : myService
      });
    }));

    it('should work', function () {

    //verify that the controller is there
    expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();

    // do test
    expect(scope.someExpectedValueSetByController).toBeDefined();
});
```

I can do a JSFiddle if you want
I can also make a better answer as my service is using $http

Please comment if you don't agree or find a better way to do it